# Windows 8.1: pagefile.sys disk response time > 1S

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I'm having a problem with Windows 8.1 using 100% of my disk.  I opened resource monitor and found that the disk response time for C:\pagefile.sys was regularly very high, usually around 500ms but sometimes around 1500 ms (1.5s).  What could be causing this?  Bad memory?

Comment: More likely, just not enough memory.

Comment: The thing is, my memory usage is below 50%

Comment: "using 100% of my disk" ? You mean the disk is full?

Comment: No, my disk usage is 100% in task manager... should've made that clearer